# ASP.NET WebApi DateTimeOffset serialize to Json/JavaScript (angular2)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, angular

I do not find a nice way to get a DateTimeOffset value to JavaScript (angular2).
I am using WebApi (5.2.3) and angular2. On the wire I see the date as follow:

```
RecordModifiedAt : "2016-03-08T17:27:11.9975483+01:00"
```

JavaScript/angular2 does not recognize this as valid datetime value.

I do have options, but what direction should I go:

- Server side: Newtonsoft.Json, ...
- Client side: angular2, ...
- Others?

Many thankx for your help!

Comment: But if you use `new Date("2016-03-08T17:27:11.9975483+01:00")`, you get a valid date object in JavaScript with the correct time and date

Comment: Thankx PierreDuc. See answer for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Thankx to PierreDuc feedback I have played around and I came to the following conclusion:

Since JSON does not support a `Date` datatype, I assume one has to make the conversion on the client side. I use the following 'pattern' (see http://codegur.com/36681078/angular-2-date-deserialization):

```
getTags() {
    return this.http.get('/api/tag/getAll')
        .map((response: Response) => this.convertData(response));
}

private convertData(response: Response) {
    var data = response.json() || [];
    data.forEach((d) => {
        // Convert to a Date datatype
        d.RecordModifiedAt = new Date(d.RecordModifiedAt);
    });
    return data;
}
```