# Angular2 parse java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, parsing, angular

Dealing with java date is my biggest fight since forever.

I just received date like for example:
`1998-01-05T00:01:00+01:00`

Is there a way to get the first 10 characters without cutting string? Angular2 offers [date pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/DatePipe-class.html) but I don't know if and how could I use that here.

Thank you for your help.

PS: java.sql.Date is not an option

Comment: Are working in javascript or in java?

Comment: Date was actually sent from backend (Java) to frontend (Angular2) as java.util.Date. Now I'm thinking how could I parse it in frontend side (typescript + javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve this problem thanks to [Angular2 DatePipe processing ISO 8601 Date (Invalid argument '*' for pipe 'DatePipe')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294955/angular2-datepipe-processing-iso-8601-date-invalid-argument-for-pipe-datep)

I've created my own pipe.